# Ionic v3 Youtube Video Player Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i try a lot of answers here but with no luck. Im using Ionic v3 and i try to play youtube video. This is my code:

[image]

Error on openVideo() function:

Object(...) is not a function

On device just dont do anything the button.

config.xml

```
<preference name="YouTubeDataApiKey" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

youtube.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player/ngx';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-youtube',
  templateUrl: 'youtube.html',
})
export class YoutubePage {

constructor(public loading: LoadingController, public http: Http, private youtube: YoutubeVideoPlayer, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {  

} 

openVideo(){ 
  this.youtube.openVideo('mX0Q2eTI250'); 
}

}
```

youtube.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Videos</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>  
  <button ion-button round icon-start color="danger" (click)="openVideo()">
  <ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon>
  Open YouTube Video
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

app.module.ts

```
.
.
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player/ngx';
.
.

@NgModule({
.
.
providers: [
  .
  .
  YoutubeVideoPlayer,
  .
  .
```

Versions:

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.0
Angular Core: 5.0.0
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.0.0
Node: 8.11.3
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) 
AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 
Safari/604.1
```

I think this is a version conflict but i dont find where.

Comment: Did you add the plugin to the app's module? If so can you add a screenshot of the exact error you get? Is the error in chrome or in terminal?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, but yes, im add it.

Comment: Picture error added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if it's an Ionic V3 project your import slightly differs from v4

```
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player';
```

So, without the `/ngx` part; make sure to properly uninstall/install the plugin as well and to change the import in the app module

Documentation for this v3 plugin can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/youtube-video-player/)